# I don't know how to change a certain part in fonts and colors in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I just downloaded a new theme for visual studios and this happened.
[image: This:]

I don't know why but I just don't like it being highlighted. I'd rather have it not been highlighted. Is there a way to change it? I couldn't find how to change it on the internet and I have been trying to do this in "fonts and colors". But I don't know how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it the highlighting of the string literal that is the problem?

Comment: all I am saying is that I would like to remove the yellow highlight of "Hello World"

Comment: but I do not know how in "fonts and colors"

Comment: Where did the theme come from?  The highlight is not a standard feature of VS 2015 so it is probably part of the theme - so you may need to look at the theme.

Comment: I downloaded a theme but I'd like to know how to change it. This is VS 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a "highlight" but just the background color. Search for display item "String" or "String - Verbatim" in the Fonts and Colors section of the Options screen.